# Max number of components in a Dynamic Placeholder with Sitecore 9

Tags: placeholders, dynamic-placeholder

Is there a way to set a minimum and max amount of components that can be inserted into a Dynamic Placeholder in Sitecore 9? There is a count and maxCount for the amount of placeholders that can be set as a parameter but what I am hoping is that there is out of the box functionality to accommodate this request when a client only wants a Content Author to be allowed to add 2 to the placeholder.

Comment: There is no setting like this OOTB for dynamic placeholders and / or also static ones. You need to implement this limitation. Take a look here https://ctor.io/limit-the-number-of-components-in-a-sitecore-placeholder/